# Is it correct and natural to say "put your phone on standby mode"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is  correct and natural to say *put your phone on standby mode*? For example:

> Don't turn off you phone. Just put it on standby mode.

Comment: I would normally say *in* standby mode.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So you would say "Put your phone in standby mode,"right?

Comment: Yes. Or perhaps on standby (without the mode), and that also refers to a person who has to be ready to go to work at short notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but as noted by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267365/standby-and-sleep-modes-in-a-mobile-phone

> Power-managment on mobile phones is quite sophisticated nowadays. Just "standby mode" and "sleep mode" are not enough to describe what is happening.

So if you are talking to a regular user then "standby" is fine.  If you are talking to an engineer then there is a lot more detail.